# Can sshuttle use an existing SSH tunnel?

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, vpn, tunnel

If server `S` can be visited through a bastion machine `B` and there's already a SSH tunnel from client `C` to the bastion server `B`, is there anyway for `sshuttle` use the existing SSH tunnel to connect the server `S`?